# How to fill the values in a textbox using Ajax or Jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Example- Consider three textboxes. In the first one, im providing ID or number ( primary key in my table). Using the ID, the semester and branch should be auto filled using the ID. ( All the three fields are in same table- in my DB).
HTML part:

```
<input type='text'  name='hosteladmissionno'>
   <input type='text'  name='student_name'>
   <input type='text'  name='semester'>
```

PHP,Mysql part:

```
<?php
session_start();
   $hostad=$_POST['hosteladmissionno'];
   $sem=$_POST['student_name'];
   $sem=$_POST['semester'];
$r1="INSERT INTO payment(hosteladmissionno)VALUES ('$hostad')";
```

Now i want the fields **student_name** and **semester** to be autofilled for the correspoinding **hosteladmissionno**. Can this be done by Ajax or Jquery? If so.. How can i implement in this Code?
Note: hosteladmissionno,student_name and semester belongs to registration tablem in my database. I need to retrieve the values from that table.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider giving the question a better title

Comment: Most puzzling question I've ever seen. Looks like just simple `value` parameter is a thing you're looking for, but I cannot be sure.

Comment: Use `<select></select>` is better. Example you select `hosteladmissionno` and it will load automatically the student name and semester. Correct?

Comment: @haha, Im not using <select> tag here. Im giving a numeric value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean auto-filled? The query that you've provided only the hosteladmissionno will be inserted. Unless you have a default value for the other column. But if you intended to insert the text you forward, you should also add it in your insert value. Something like this.

```
$r1 = "INSERT INTO payment(hosteladmissionno, student_name, semester)VALUES ('$hostad','$sem_student_name','$sem_semester')";
```

I don't know why you use the same variable in two different field. Does only the last initialization will be its value.

See some tutorials:

[Post MySQL Result Using AJAX via jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717052/post-mysql-result-using-ajax-via-jquery)

[JQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

[PHP tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info)

[jquery -> php -> mysql](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-jquery-ajax/index.html)

Comment: Cheers. Thats the answer im looking for!